# Where clause with Aggregation function on SparkSQL Thriftserver connected with beeline

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am connected to spark thrift (Spark SQL version 2.3.1 and Hive JDBC 1.2.1.spark2) from beeline and want to execute below query.

Select * from table1 where age > avg(age);

But I am getting error "UnsupportedOpertionException"

Request you to help..

Comment: Mahesh, could you please provide the schema of the table as well?

Comment: your are using aggregate functions without using group by function

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

Hive support sub queries on with `in/exists/notin/notexists`

```
with avg_age as
(select avg(age) as age1 from table1),
select * from table1 t1, avg_age t2 where t1.age>t2.age.
```

Or use joins.

```
select * from table1 t1 inner join
(select avg(age) as age1 from table1) t2
on t1.<UniqCol>=t2.<UniqCol> where t1.age>t2.age.
```